# Listening for RabbitMQ server startup

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a Java application that expects the RabbitMQ Server to be up when the application starts up, and will connect to it if available.  However if the RabbitMQ Server is down when the application starts up and comes up later, is there a way that my application be notified of it so it can try to connect? Basically I want to avoid having to poll the RabbitMQ server again and again to try to connect to it. If my application could pre-register as an AMQP client to be notified at RabbitMQ startup that would be ideal. But I couldn't find out from the docs how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately RabbitMQ itself does not support this. I think its quite an unrealistic desire... The message queue might be unavailable since the entire machine that hosts it is done, etc.
The best approach in your case would be polling for the connection on a separate thread to allow the main application flow to run, and notifying once a connection is successfully established.

Comment: The machine that boots up and starts my Java application could happen to do so before the machine hosting the message queue.  Why would you characterize this concern as an unrealistic desire?

Comment: Due to the wish that this be done without actively polling the RabbitMQ server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After no answers on SO, I posted my question elsewhere and one of the RabbitMQ developers responded thus:

> You have three options:
>
> - `rabbitmqctl wait [pid file path]` which requires that you know
>     what the node's PID file path is. This is inconvenient and only works
>     on the local machine.
> - `rabbitmqctl await_online_nodes [N] --timeout [timeout]`
>     that waits until a cluster of N nodes is formed (of course
>     N can equal 1)
> - You can poll one of the ports used by the node [1]
>     (which will be active depends on the protocol(s) used)

I wanted to avoid doing the poll from my application.
I feel the best solution for me to use is something like the java WatchService (in java.nio.file) that can watch the RabbitMQ log-file for changes and code around that can notify my application one-time-only via REST when it is changed.  To be sure, when notified my watcher can look within the log-file for a timestamped line that contains the phrase "Starting RabbitMQ".

Comment: I used `rabbitmqctl wait --pid 1 --timeout 60` within a docker container and it works great.

Comment: @BenoitGalati It works like magic! But why it works?

Comment: It works because within a Docker container the pid of the main process is always 1.